# FASTQC runs on command line but not in python subprocess (Java exception)

Tags: java, python, fonts, subprocess, bioinformatics

The command line tool I'm using works fine when calling it from the Linux command line, but gives an exception when I am calling it via the Python `subprocess` module.  I have looked at the previous posts relating to this, but none of them address how it would work on the command line but not in Python.

This is a sample of the traceback that I get:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.Error: Probable fatal error:No fonts found.
at sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1236)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1100)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1037)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1054)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2256)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1220)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1100)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1037)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1054)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2256)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1220)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1100)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1037)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1054)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2256)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1220)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1100)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1037)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1054)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2256)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1220)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1100)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1037)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1054)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2256)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1220)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1100)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1037)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1054)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2256)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1220)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1100)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1037)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1054)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2256)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1220)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1100)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1037)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1054)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2256)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1220)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1100)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1037)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1054)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2256)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1220)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1100)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1037)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1054)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2256)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1220)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1100)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1037)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1054)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2256)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1220)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1100)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1037)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1054)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2256)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1220)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1100)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1037)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1054)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2256)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1220)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1100)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1037)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1054)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2256)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1220)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1100)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1037)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1054)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2256)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1220)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1100)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1037)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1054)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2256)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1220)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1100)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1037)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1054)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2256)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1220)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1100)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1037)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1054)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2256)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1220)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:1106)
at sun.font.CompositeFont.doDeferredInitialisation(CompositeFont.java:263)
at sun.font.CompositeFont.getSlotFont(CompositeFont.java:352)
at sun.font.CompositeStrike.getStrikeForSlot(CompositeStrike.java:78)
at sun.font.CompositeStrike.getFontMetrics(CompositeStrike.java:93)
at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.initMatrixAndMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:359)
at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.<init>(FontDesignMetrics.java:350)
at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:302)
at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.getFontMetrics(SunGraphics2D.java:855)
at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Graphs.QualityBoxPlot.paint(QualityBoxPlot.java:88)
at javax.swing.JComponent.print(JComponent.java:1202)
at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Modules.AbstractQCModule.writeDefaultImage(AbstractQCModule.java:68)
at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Modules.PerBaseQualityScores.makeReport(PerBaseQualityScores.java:199)
at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Report.HTMLReportArchive.<init>(HTMLReportArchive.java:131)
at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Analysis.OfflineRunner.analysisComplete(OfflineRunner.java:178)
at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Analysis.AnalysisRunner.run(AnalysisRunner.java:110)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm calling the tool like this:

```
def runCommand(self, command, directory):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=directory)
    out,err = process.communicate()

    if out:
        self.logger.info("Standard output: \n" + out.decode('utf-8') + "\n")
    if err:
        self.logger.info("Standard error: \n" + err.decode('utf-8') + "\n")
```

With **command** being the same command that I use to run it on the command line.

I checked to ensure that the java version called form the command line is the same as the one called using `subprocess`.  It might be that the environment is modified somehow when running it in `subprocess`, but how can I ensure the font package is used in java?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I have used to run fastqc from python.  It uses subprocess.check_call instead of Popen.

```
def run(fastq_path, output_dir, options=['--extract',]):
    """
    Run the fastqc program on a specified fastq file and return the output directory path.

    Parameters
    ----------
    fastq_path : str
        Path to the fastq file to analyze.
    output_dir : str
        Directory where output will be written. It will be created if it does not exist.
    options : list of str (optional)
        Command-line flags and options to fastqc. Default is --extract.

    Returns
    -------
    output_dir : str
        The path to the directory containing the detailed output for this fastq file.
        It will be a subdirectory of the specified output dir.
    """
    utils.mkdir_p(output_dir)

    command = "fastqc {} -o {} {}".format(' '.join(options), output_dir, fastq_path)
    subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True)

    # Fastqc creates a directory derived from the basename
    fastq_dir = os.path.basename(fastq_path)
    if fastq_dir.endswith(".gz"):
        fastq_dir = fastq_dir[0:-3]
    if fastq_dir.endswith(".fq"):
        fastq_dir = fastq_dir[0:-3]
    if fastq_dir.endswith(".fastq"):
        fastq_dir = fastq_dir[0:-6]
    fastq_dir = fastq_dir + "_fastqc"

    # Delete the zip file and keep the uncompressed directory
    zip_file = os.path.join(output_dir, fastq_dir + ".zip")
    os.remove(zip_file)

    output_dir = os.path.join(output_dir, fastq_dir)
    return output_dir
```